# Saving Cookie for List Grid View

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to save the state of the selected class to cookie and read it back but somehow it would not do his job.

Javascript

```
function switchStyle(ed, style)
{
   $('.styled_view:last > div > div').each(function(idx, item) {
      $(item).removeClass('list').removeClass('gallery').removeClass('mosaic');
      $(item).addClass(style);
   });

   $('#ed_list, #ed_gallery, #ed_mosaic').removeClass('active');
   $('#ed_' + style).addClass('active');

   $.cookie('switchStyle', style);
   xajax_setzeErweiterteDarstellung(ed);

}
```

Template Code

```
{assign var="style" value="list"}
{if isset($oErweiterteDarstellung) && isset($Einstellungen.artikeluebersicht.artikeluebersicht_erw_darstellung) && $Einstellungen.artikeluebersicht.artikeluebersicht_erw_darstellung === 'Y'}
    {if $oErweiterteDarstellung->nDarstellung == 1}
        {assign var="style" value="list"}
    {elseif $oErweiterteDarstellung->nDarstellung == 2}
        {assign var="style" value="gallery"}
    {elseif $oErweiterteDarstellung->nDarstellung == 3}
        {assign var="style" value="mosaic"}
    {/if}
{/if}

<a id="ed_list" onclick="switchStyle('1', 'list');return false;" class="btn btn-default ed list {if $oErweiterteDarstellung->nDarstellung == 1}active{/if}"></a>
<a id="ed_gallery" onclick="switchStyle('2', 'gallery');return false;" class="btn btn-default ed gallery {if $oErweiterteDarstellung->nDarstellung == 2}active{/if}"></a>
```

Comment: Can you tell us, what is not working. your function is able to set the correct cookie value, as it seems.

Comment: It does not get the class back which has been set.

Comment: Can you show us what ``xajax_setzeErweiterteDarstellung`` is doing and how it connects to your template (PHP??). We are missing  the essential part of your code, I think.

Comment: The Problem is that most of the part of the source code is hardcoded :( I just have access to template and thats all as Code I have.

Comment: Can you explain, how ``xajax_setzeErweiterteDarstellung`` and ``$Einstellungen.artikeluebersicht.artikeluebersicht_erw_darstellung === 'Y'`` in your template is connected? Where is the cookie, you set earlier read on PHP/Smarty side evaluated?

Comment: `$Einstellungen.artikeluebersicht.artikeluebersicht_erw_darstellung === 'Y'` if is set on Admin true or false but as the most part of the Script is protected by IonCube, I cant get more informations.

Comment: I have to pass on this.